# Broadcast across network for app pairing

Tags: c#, networking

**EDIT** - On hold until I do further research on specifics for my question.

I am looking to create a service in which two different computer's on the same network will run my app. How can I broadcast across the network that computer A is running my app so that computer B can find it and then begin sharing information.

To me this sounds like sockets, however I have never worked with local networking in C#. I am not familiar with any form of discovery using C# either.

Also what kind of network performance issues could I see, when both apps are broadcasting for a partner on the network?

Comment: Sounds like UDP unicast to me...

Comment: I am only a second year in college and they haven't touched on programming mixing with networking yet.

Comment: SO Isn't really the place for full tutorials/programs. I would try to narrow down your question a bit; maybe do some research on UDP (hint `UdpClient`) and come back with something more specific. Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Broadcasting should only ever be used if you really need to interrupt _every_ host on a LAN. It doesn't sound appropriate four your use. You should probably use unicast or multicast.

Comment: I think my problem was I didn't know what this technology was called. I am not very familiar with the all the networking protocols in regards to sharing simple unreliable data. I am going to leave this here, and do research creating a UdpHost and a UdpClient and see if I can get some demo code to ask a question about. @BradleyDotNET

Answer (score 1):

One way you could try doing this, is to get the app to send some piece of data to the server when it connects over UDP, thereby notifying you that the app is running.

You could then store a list of clients which connected (I think this will be a `List<IPEndPoint>` and notify all of these endpoints once another client connects.

Hopefully this makes sense, below is a simple UDP example you can use to get started.

**Note:** If you open the client app from the same computer twice, this will register as 2 clients on the server, so if you need to identify unique computers you may want to do a check for this.

---

1. Create 2 Console Applications

   - `UdpServerExample`
   - `UdpClientExample`
2. Place the following code in the Server `Program.cs`.

   - This simply creates a `UdpClient` object and tells it to listen on the specified port (`11000` in this case).
   - If any data is received, it will be converted to a string and print the string to the console before sending a response message.

     ```
     var udpServer = new UdpClient(11000);

     while (true)
     {
         // Create endpoint and listen on port 11000
         var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
         var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);

         // Convert the byte array to string and display the client address + message
         var stringData = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
         Console.WriteLine($"receive data from {remoteEP} - {stringData}");

         // Send response back to the client
         var stringToSend = "Message received";
         var bytesToSend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringToSend);
         udpServer.Send(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.Length, remoteEP);
     }
     ```
3. Now place this code in the Client `Program.cs`

   - Here we create a `UdpClient`, which connects to the server with the specified port and IP
   - Then we create a byte array from the string `"Hello, World!` and send it to across the network.
   - Any response sent back from the server is printed to the conosole

     ```
     // Create udp client and connect using the server IP and specified port
     var client = new UdpClient();
     var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000); 
     client.Connect(ep);

     // Convert string to byte array and send 
     var stringToSend = "Hello, World!";
     var bytesToSend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringToSend);
     client.Send(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.Length);

     // Receive the response
     var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ep);
     var receivedString = Encoding.Default.GetString(receivedData);

     Console.WriteLine($"receive data from {ep} - {receivedString}");

     Console.Read();
     ```

You can test it out by executing `UdpServerExample.exe`, and at the same time stepping through `UdpClientExample` in VS.

You should see this in the Server console window after `client.Send(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.Length);` is called in the client:

[image]

And in the client console (once the dat has been received):

[image]

Comment: This looks really cool thank you very much. I was also thinking I could host a SignalR hub on the computer acting as the server, and once the computers know each other ip addresses connect to each other using SignalR for faster more robust communication.

Comment: Only question though on the client program, how will it know the ip address of the acting server, if they have never communicated before? Two separate computers on the same network looking for each other.

Comment: @BaileyMiller You will have to just enter the ip of the server. For me it defaults to the value shown when running throuh VS or running the exe

Comment: But I am looking for automatic discovery of clients on the network running my app.

Comment: @BaileyMiller I'm afraid I don't understand your question. If the client is going to be communicating with a server surely you will need to know the address?

Comment: The "server" is just another app running on a different computer on the network. Example, computer A is my laptop running my app, computer B is my desktop, I open the app on computer B and want to connect to computer A  running the same app. Computer A's Ip address may change so how do I auto discover it?

Comment: @BaileyMiller The ip address should be available in the `remoteEp` variable on the server

Comment: I'll have to test this demo later. I am currently not free at the moment to test.